# EPPlus how to add trendline using ExcelChartTrendline?

Tags: epplus

I need to add a trendline to an Excel scatterplot. There's a class in the EPPlus library - ExcelChartTrendline.cs - that is clearly intended to support this. There is also an Enum - eTrendLine that allows me to specify the type of line.

The code for adding the scatterplot was simple and the chart renders fine:

```
var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(chartName, eChartType.XYScatter);
```

But after a many hours searching and tinkering I cannot figure out the syntax for adding the trendline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get reference to the `serie` that is created when adding the chart series to access the `TrendLines` collection.  Like this:

```
var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart test", eChartType.XYScatter);
var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells["B1:B10"], worksheet.Cells["A1:A10"]);
series.TrendLines.Add(eTrendLine.Linear);
```

Comment: For future visitors: You are not limited to one trendline on a chart. If you are trying to demonstrate to the viewer the polynomial nature of a series it's interesting to add both a linear and a polynomial trendline.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This page is the first on Google about trendlines in EPPlus. Any idea how to change style of trendline? (color, thickness)

Comment: @TNT I think you will have to use XML to do it.  If you use the extension method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520427/legend-color-is-incorrect-in-excel-chart-created-using-epplus/36532733#36532733  you should be able to do it by pointing it at the right spot in the XML.  If you get stuck post a separate question with your code.